# Acces dictionary items from json list object

Tags: python, json

I have this kind of json data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "alpha": 1.93358, 
      "beta": 1.98596, 
      "confidence": 0.051
    }, 
    {
      "alpha": 1.92124, 
      "beta": 3.91954, 
      "confidence": 0.207
    },
    ...
```

and I want just `beta` values.

What I did was using list comprehension:

`[x['beta'] for x in data]`

but for some reason I feel that there is more appropriate way to parse this dictionary and get the same data, and I don't see it.

Is there better way?

Comment: Looks good to me... why do you think this way is bad?

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, I just thought there is some json trick, and wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks perfect to me. I'm sure you're already using the json loader to interpret this into a python dictionary, but just in-case you're not familiar example is below:

```
import json

def get_data(json_data) :
    data = json.loads(json_data)['data']
    return [x['beta'] for x in data]
```